# Big picture google analytics traffic

Tags: google-analytics

I have a domain with multiple subdomains.  I have already set up tracking for the top level domain and the subdomains.  I know I can add up all the numbers to get the big picture, but I am using a computer so why should I have to add anything.

Is there a way to get the big picture from google analytics so that I can see that the top domain and the subdomains are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Run them all to the same account number, with the cookie domain as the top level domain, and then have 1 profile for a "master" view, and a view for each subdomain (via filters). I'd suggest on the master view you add in a filter that adds the domain name, as such:

```
Custom Filter
Filter Type:  Advanced
FieldA: [Hostname]    (.*)
FieldB: [Request URI] (.*)
Output: [Request URI] $A1$B1
```

The "master" view would then rollup all of your numbers and each of the subdomain views would allow you to see more specific data.